# C++ makefile: How to extract *.o files to a spesific folder?

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation

My makefile working when I remove **$(OBJ_DIR)** but I want my *.o files to extracted to be in lib folder.

Here is my makefile:

```
CC=g++

vpath %.h include
vpath %.cpp src
vpath %.o lib

OUT_DIR = bin
OBJDIR = lib

CFLAGS = -O2 -Wall -pedantic
LIBS = -lnsl -lm

OBJS = $(OBJDIR)/main.o $(OBJDIR)/AVLTree.o $(OBJDIR)/AVLTreeNode.o $(OBJDIR)/PersonData.o $(OBJDIR)/Stack.o

all:program

program:$(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(OUT_DIR)/program -static-libstdc++

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

.PHONY : clean
clean :
    rm -f *.o $(OUT_DIR)/main.exe
```

and it gives this error:

```
> g++: error: lib/main.o: No such file or directory g++: error:
> lib/AVLTree.o: No such file or directory g++: error:
> lib/AVLTreeNode.o: No such file or directory g++: error:
> lib/PersonData.o: No such file or directory g++: error: lib/Stack.o:
> No such file or directory
```

[image]

.o files created in Projects folder but They must be in lib folder.

```
CC=g++

vpath %.h include
vpath %.cpp src
vpath %.o lib

OUT_DIR = bin
OBJDIR = lib

CFLAGS = -O2 -Wall -pedantic
LIBS = -lnsl -lm

OBJS = $(OBJDIR)/main.o $(OBJDIR)/AVLTree.o $(OBJDIR)/AVLTreeNode.o $(OBJDIR)/PersonData.o $(OBJDIR)/Stack.o

all:program

program:$(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(OUT_DIR)/program -static-libstdc++

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -c -o  $@ $<

.PHONY : clean
clean :
    rm -f *.o $(OUT_DIR)/main.exe
```

I dont know why but now it works perfectly!

Comment: Is the `:` in `OBJ_DIR := lib` intentional?

Comment: I just see at documentation at GNU web site and put it yes it is intentional.

Comment: Would you mind minimizing the example? There are many variables that are empty, namely CPPFLAGS and CXXFLAGS

Comment: Try removing the `vpath %.o` line.

Comment: it works now I didnt change anything though.(It worked before I remove empty varaibles too)